# Linking to url from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, scroll

I'm redesigning my portfolio based on this pen. It's an infinitve loop fetching content from index.js: 
: http://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/KpmRRy

```
$scope.forests = [
        {
            'url'   : 'fersk.html',
            'image' : 'images/front/fersk.jpg'

        },
```

I want each image to be a link to another page.

I tried to do this in HTML but it's not working:

```
        <a href="{{ article.url }}">    
    <article visible visible-model="article.visible"
                     ng-class="{ 'visible' : article.visible }"
                     ng-repeat="article in forests"
                     ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                <figure ng-style="{ 'background-image' : 'url(' + article.image + ')' }"></figure>
            </article></a>
```

Any ideas how to get this to work? You can check out my work in progress here: http://marteteigen.no/ny2/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you try out to use `ng-href` instead of the normal `href`. Check this Docs out for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: I got it working. Here is an updated example: http://codepen.io/morrisjdev/pen/grEzjN ... By the way: I would recommand you to look into the library safeApply (https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.SafeApply) to avoid error with $apply()

Comment: It' strange. If I wrap the atag around the figure, like you did:

'code' <a ng-href="{{article.link}}" target="_blank">   
<figure ng-style="{ 'background-image' : 'url(' + article.image + ')' }"></figure>
</a>'code'

the images disappear. I uploaded the latest version here: http://marteteigen.no/ny2/index.html 

As you can see there are no images now.

Comment: Other option would be to use ng-click and than use location.href inside a function to set a new location.